# autoplay=1 not working for <iframe> in playing video in mobile devices

Tags: html, ios, video, iframe, autoplay

I'm working with video. When i click on Video Thumbnail a pop appears and Video plays in that,I need to start play the video (without clicking the play button) when popup opened.I tried with code below.

It was working perfect in web but not in mobile devices like iPhone ,iPad

```
<iframe
        title="YouTube video player"
        id="videoFrame"
        class="youtube_iframe" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?wmode=opaque&amp;autoplay=1"
        frameborder="0"   width="395" height="280"        allowfullscreen=""        scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

But not auto played when video is opend in popup.
thankx in advancee

Answer (score 3):

To add muted in an iframe link use it like "&muted=1". The complete link will be something like:

```
<iframe id="video-iframe" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/125472391?api=1&player_id=video-iframe&autoplay=1&muted=1&loop=1&color=ffffff" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

chrome Android 53 and above supports autoplay
and IOS 10 + supports autoplay 
you need to use *muted* and *autoplay* attributes in the video tag

`<video  width="465" height="315" muted autoplay src="movie.mp4"></video>`

chrome docs [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay)

Comment: OP is asking about the `iframe` element, not `video`.