# Dynamic playlist with autoplay

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm having trouble embedding a dynamic playlist with autoplay.

What I'm trying to do is, having a dynamic list of video IDs, embed a playlist with those videos. I'm doing this by updating a div with the following HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?playlist=<VIDEO_IDS_COMMA_SEPARATED>&autoplay=1 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#playlist).

However, the `autoplay` attribute seems to be ignored, since the initial video doesn't get started.

In other cases, I'm setting the `src` to embed a single video, with

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<VIDEO_ID>&autoplay=1 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and this works great.

Does anyone know how can I force an autoplay on a dynamic embedded playlist?

--------------------- EDIT-------------------------

It seems this is working on IE, but not on Firefox nor on Chrome... Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: does this question have any relevance to this one? - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498032/autoplay-1-not-working-for-iframe-in-playing-video-in-mobile-devices and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676660/autoplay-with-iframe-you-tube-video-autoplay-1-not-working

Comment: @ruslan I'm afraid not... The first link is regarding an iframe not autoplaying on an iPhone, which, accordingly to the answer, is Apple's policy. I'm testing this on a Windows machine, with various browsers. It seems however to be working on IE, but not on Firefox nor or Chrome. The second link is regarding a mistyped attribute, which is not the case...

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-get-YouTube-playlist-to-autoplay-in-embedded-player), you need to add `"&autoplay=1&loop=1"` in your YouTube playlist link.

Example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<VIDEO_ID>&autoplay=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Check this related SO question:

- [How can I autoplay a video using the new embed code style for Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405242/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video-using-the-new-embed-code-style-for-youtube)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've tried this already, but the loop attribute only sets the loop feature for the playlist, which I don't want it to be set. Even with `loop=1` attribute, the autoplay still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find, related answer, but looks like problem can be in [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).